# when i try insert query(insert) to if condition, then double insert?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mariadb

`$get_id_siswa = check` if the student available before, if not available then insert and if available then update

```
if(!$get_id_siswa){
$this->User_Model->insert($datax);
$user_id = $this->db->insert_id();
$datay['user_id'] = $user_id;
$datay['role_id'] = 17;
$this->load->model('User_Role_Model');
$this->User_Role_Model->insert($datay);
}else if ($get_id_asesi->nama_user == $nama_lengkap && $get_id_asesi->id_asesi == '0') {
$data_asesi_update = array('id_asesi' => $id);
$this->db->where('id', $get_id_asesi->id);
$this->db->update('t_users', $data_asesi_update);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you want to achieve ? And where are you going wrong ?  what error you are getting ?

Comment: Even if your question was  clear, we don't have enough information on some of the variables you are using in your conditional statements to understand what you are doing.

Comment: if not available then insert and if available then update: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists

Comment: `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...;`